# Exception not bubbling up from parent constructor

Tags: php

My exception does not seem to be bubbling up from the parent constructor.

Here's a simplified version:

```
class importer {

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->getFile(); // fills out $file with name or false on failure

        if (!$this->file) {
            throw new Exception("Sorry no file, so no can do!");
        }
    }

}

class childImporter extends importer {

    pubclic function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

}

try {

    new childImporter();

    nextFunction();

} catch (Exception $e) {

    echo $e->getMessage();

}
```

`nextFunction` never gets called, and the catch block doesn't get run either, the whole thing throws an uncaught exception fault and stops.

I thought exceptions were supposed to bubble up?

Or is the code above supposed to work and something else is going wrong?

Comment: `pubclic` isn't in your real code, right ?

Comment: Are there namespaces involved? Because if so, `Exception` might be referring to a different class in each case.

Comment: Exception is being caught - http://ideone.com/Humycm (see stdout)

Comment: Clément, no! I think this whole thing has shown that I have been working for far too long today!

Comment: Mark Baker did not know about this place to run php code! Nice!

Comment: @mattl - http://3v4l.org is another very good site, because it shows the outputs for all different versions of PHP

Comment: Ooo that is nice! Thanks for the find.

Answer (score 1):

So for anyone else having a similar issue the problem was, as cbuckley pointed out, an issue with namespacing.

I changed both occurrences of `Exception` to `\Exception` which caught it nicely.

I wasn't getting any other namespace errors in my ide as PHPStorm had very nicely auto-imported an exception class of `Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\Exception` from who knows where (as I am not using any Symfony components anywhere else!).

Hope this helps someone who has also had a really long day!